# parsing json object and accessing a specific element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to parse this json object.

```
{"coord"=>{"lon"=>-0.13, "lat"=>51.51}, "sys"=>{"message"=>0.2063, "country"=>"GB", "sunrise"=>1387958729, "sunset"=>1387986980}, "weather"=>[{"id"=>801, "main"=>"Clouds", "description"=>"few clouds", "icon"=>"02n"}], "base"=>"gdps stations", "main"=>{"temp"=>276.49, "pressure"=>983, "temp_min"=>275.37, "temp_max"=>277.59, "humidity"=>95}, "wind"=>{"speed"=>0.51, "gust"=>1.54, "deg"=>229}, "rain"=>{"3h"=>0}, "clouds"=>{"all"=>24}, "dt"=>1387950679, "id"=>2643743, "name"=>"London", "cod"=>200}
```

Here is my code:

```
class WeatherController < ApplicationController
  def index
    require 'json'
    response = HTTParty.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk')
    response.each do |key, value|
      puts "key = #{key}, value = #{value}"
    end
    response.each do |item|
      puts item
    end
  end
end
```

The two loops work and go through the object. In the item loop shouldn't I be able to do something like puts item.coord to just get that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use directly `response['coord']` in your code, you don't need to do any looks. And you can check if its nil and handle this situation